# javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined: jquery-csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I am trying to use the jQuery CSV parser plugin. However I got this console message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined.

My code is

```
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "the-correct-path.html/fakeaddata.csv",
        async: false,
        success: function (csvd) {
            data = $.csv.objects(csvd);
        },
        dataType: "text",
        complete: function () {
            document.getElementById("lastupdate").innerHTML = data;
            // call a function on complete 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Error pretty simple $.csv return undefined that's why you got this error. Check you spelling. Maybe it should be $.(csv) or something like this. Hope this helps. Also check if you enable plugin in your document before using this code.

Comment: Also, regarding docs https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv you need to call .fromObjects(), not objects. Try it

Comment: @Nigrimmist This won't magically fill `$.csv` with life ;)

Comment: @Nigrimmist, thanks actually according to the docs I needed to call toObjects(). However I got the same problem :(

Comment: Go to the console and enter $.csv, what do you see? if undefined - you need to include .js properly i think

Comment: It says undefined yes, however I have included it like any other .js file with this in the header:
'<script src="js/jq/src/jquery.csv.js"></script>'

Comment: With some moving around it now magically works :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be $.csv.toObjects(),

In your code replace `$.csv.objects(csvd);` to `$.csv.toObjects(csvd),`

PS: Mind that semi-colon at the end of your code. Repleace it with a comma.